# Php foreach loop in the timeslots intervals and return only quarter time if between is free

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a mySQL table 'timeslots' with columns "intervals" and "reserved". How i can loop through it and return only intervals which are on 15 minutes but the interval which "cut" 15 minutes must be reserved = 0. For example i should loop through a column "intervals" and return 08:15:00 but skip 08:00:00 because 08:08:00 interval is reserved (column reserved = 1), also i should skip interval 08:45:00 because 08:53:00 is reserved = 1. I have attached the image of the table for this question.

I have been trying to find a solution for this for a days but with no success.

[image]

```
public function getTimeSlots($app)
{
$timeslots = Timeslot::where('app', '=', $app)->where('reserved', '=', 0)->orderBy('intervals', 'ASC')->get();
    $timeslotlist = array();

    foreach ($timeslots as $timeSlot) {

        $timeslotlist[] = array(
            'id' => $timeSlot['id'],
            'app' => $timeSlot['app'],
            'intervals' => $timeSlot['intervals'],
            'reserved' => $timeSlot['reserved'],
        );
    }
   return json_encode($timeslotlist);
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the code that you have tried that is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to get the reserved slots. then check in the loop whether the slot has next reserved slot.

```
public function getTimeSlots($app)
{
$reservedSlots = Timeslot::where('app', '=', $app)->where('reserved', '=', 1)->orderBy('intervals', 'ASC')->get();
$timeslots = Timeslot::where('app', '=', $app)->where('reserved', '=', 0)->orderBy('intervals', 'ASC')->get();
    $timeslotlist = array();

    foreach ($timeslots as $timeSlot) {
        $haveNextReservedSlot = array_filter($reservedSlots, function($v) use($timeSlot){ 
             $start_date = new DateTime($timeSlot['date'].' '.$timeSlot['intervals']);
             $since_start = $start_date->diff(new DateTime($v['date'].' '.$v['intervals']));
             return $since_start->i < 15; //if difference less than 15 min
      });
        if($haveNextReservedSlot) continue;

        $timeslotlist[] = array(
            'id' => $timeSlot['id'],
            'app' => $timeSlot['app'],
            'intervals' => $timeSlot['intervals'],
            'reserved' => $timeSlot['reserved'],
        );
    }
   return json_encode($timeslotlist);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to convert the collection to array, then it would be easier to compare the previous time slot and the next time slot, e.g.

```
public function getTimeSlots($app)
{
    $timeslots = Timeslot::where('app', '=', $app)->orderBy('intervals', 'ASC')->get()->toArray();
    $timeslotlist = array();

    for($i=0;$i<count($timeslots);$i++){
        $current_slot=strtotime($timeslots[$i]->date." ".$timeslots[$i]->intervals);
        if(date('i',$current_slot) % 15===0){
            if((isset($timeslots[$i-1]) && $timeslots[$i-1]->reserved) or
                (isset($timeslots[$i+1]) && $timeslots[$i+1]->reserved)){
            }
            else{
                $timeslotlist[]=$timeslots[$i];
            }
        }

    }
    return json_encode($timeslotlist);
}
```

And this will return 08:30. Is this what you want?